# Jquery Masonry layout, forcing content into specific columns

Tags: jquery

I'm using masonry for my layout. I'm using only 2 div widths for the content boxes, 240px and 500px. What I'd like to do is always force the 500px boxes into the middle of the layout so I have a more orderly thin thick thin layout. I created a jpeg that demonstrates what I want to achieve.

[image]

I dug into the code of the jquery.masonry.js file to try and figure it out. The best I've achieved so far is manipulating the X position of the div, but when I do that it doesn't adjust the Y pos and throws off the height calculation of further divs. query is not my first language and I'm having a hard time figuring out how each column's Y height is calculated. Anyone dug into masonry to do this before?

What I've achieved is this:

```
      if($brick.width() === 240) { 
      //code here to make sure this div's x position is either 5 or 785

     if($brick.width() > 260) { 
     //code here to make sure this divs x position is set at 265
```

But after I reposition these divs the Y pos is thrown off and as I loop through the content further divs Y pos will be off.

You can see the original full masonry js here: https://github.com/desandro/masonry/blob/master/jquery.masonry.js

Comment: The question is a bit hidden. You might want to explain what you want to do, what you've done so far and then conclude with what you need to have answered.

Comment: Not sure how to say it any better. I made a jpeg you can see which illustrates what I want to do, I've been able to manipulate the x position of the divs within the masonry layout but that's all. And at this point I still don't understand the code well enough (which you can view at the github link) to foce containers of a specific width into a specific column

Answer (score 0):

Add `horizontalOrder: true` to your function and it will force left-to-right.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to create 3 masonry containers; left, middle, right. Although I'm not entirely sure why you're using masonry, seems over the top for this simple layout. I guess it makes it easier for a responsive site but still, I believe you could achieve your jpeg with CSS.